Find all pairs $(m,n)$ of integers such that $m^2 + 2mn - n^2 = 1$
The question is given above:
So I have solved this question using Pell's equation method which is somewhat like this:
$m^2 + 2mn - n^2 = 1$
$(m+n)^2 - 2n^2 = 1$
let $m+n = x$ 
$x^2 - 2n^2 = 1$
And there is a entire method of evaluating the continued fraction of $\sqrt 2 = [1;\bar 2]$ then finding the $\frac{x_1}{n_1} = \frac{3}{2}$ and get the format of x and n both
There are infinite solutions to this as a format of x and n both comes.
But I am in search of some other approaches which can be done to this question.

There a slightly easier way to write the set of roots to this Pell equation. Once you have the smallest root, here $(x,n)=(3,2),$ you get $x_k+n_k\sqrt2=(3+2\sqrt2)^k.$

I doubt there is a real way to solve this in any other way, without just hiding the fact that you writing the solution of the Pell equation, and just reproducing that.

You can also observe that if $(m,n)$ is one solution, then $(m+2n,2m+5n)$ is another. But I reverse engineered the solution of the Pell equation to come up with that. In other words, I agree with Thomas in the sense that it all comes to much the same thing. Some might want to reformulate this as (generalized?) Vieta jumping, but that won't change the scene.

@Jyrki ,  your mapping, for binary $a x^2 + bxy + c y^2$   with $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac,$  comes from a solution of $\tau^2 - \Delta  \sigma^2 = 4$   and matrix  $$\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{\tau - b \sigma}{2} & -c \sigma \
a \sigma & \frac{\tau + b \sigma}{2}  \
\end{array}
\right)
$$  Note $\tau$  is the trace, which leads to the Fibonacci type sequences $w_{n+2} = \tau ,  w_{n+1}  - w_n$  where $w$  is either $x_n$ or $y_n$  in $ax^2 + bxy + c y^2 = M$  for fixed target $M$

If $(p,q)$ is a root of $x^2-2n^2=1$ , we get $$(p+q\sqrt2)(p-q\sqrt2)=1$$And, $p+q\sqrt2\in\mathbb{N}[\sqrt2]$ . Thus , $$p+q\sqrt2=\pm(1+\sqrt2)^n \implies p^2+2q^2=\pm1\\ \because  (1+\sqrt2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom n k1^{n-k}(\sqrt2)^k=\sum_{\text{k even}}\binom n k2^{k/2}+\sum_{\text{k odd}}\binom n k2^{(k-1)/2}\sqrt2$$
So , $(1+\sqrt2)^n$ alternates between solutions to $x^2-2n^2=1$ and $x^2-2n^2=-1$

For odd $n$ , $(1+\sqrt2)^n$ satisfies $x^2-2n^2=-1$
For even $n$ , $(1+\sqrt2)^n$ satisfies $x^2-2n^2=1$

$$\therefore p+q\sqrt2=\pm(1+\sqrt2)^{2n} , n\in\mathbb{Z}$$

as (p,q) = (3,2) and then $p+q\sqrt 2 = \pm(1+\sqrt 2)^3$ for $n = 3$ then
$p+q\sqrt 2 = (1+\sqrt 2)^3 = 7 + 5\sqrt 2 \implies p = 7 $ and $ q = 5$, but when applied in the main equation it results in -1 rather than +1, please correct me if my calculations are wrong

@NamenotAllowed you're right. I'll edit the post to clarify. Thanks for pointing it out.
